# Giving input of different sizes to LSTM model in keras

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I have a multi-class(4-class) classification model in keras which looks like  [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVkxx.png)

While training, the model expects the input shape to be (None,None,300). That is, If there are 'n' different input sequences, then the input shape should be (n,None,300). In my case, the size of each input sequence is different.
Say, the input sequences are of shapes (1000,300), (1500,300), (1200,300) and (2000,300). Now I need to put them together to (4,None,300). I tried using numpy array, but numpy array won't give shape of (4,None,300),instead it will be (4L,).

Now I want to know how to train my model? Is it possible to do with numpy arrays or any different data structures are available?

Comment: how do you expect to fit into a 3D tensor 1000x3m 1500x3, 1200x3 and 2000x3 matrices? there's no common duration for the sequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your sequences are of different duration, you may consider padding them with zeros (adjusting the loss/labels accordingly) and then

```
max_duration = 2000
in_ = np.zeros((4, max_duration, 300), dtype='f4')
for i in xrange(4):
    # fit sequence
    in_[i,:len(seq[i]),:] = seq[i]
```

Comment: Using the Masking layer should avoid having to adjust the loss!